# How to launch Configure Kde control module by command line?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, window-manager, kwin

Right-clicking on the top bar of a window gets you, via "Configure Window Behavior", to the Window Manager settings. Here you can learn and configure the advanced features of KWin.

But is there a way to launch Window Manager settings using the command line?

Answer (score 20):

**KDE Control Modules**

Command:

```
kcmshell4 --help
```

Will tell:

```
Usage: kcmshell4 [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] module 

A tool to start single KDE control modules

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --list                    List all possible modules

Arguments:
  module                    Configuration module to open
  --lang <language>         Specify a particular language
  --silent                  Do not display main window
  --args <arguments>        Arguments for the module
```

You could use list command:

```
kcmshell4 --list

The following modules are available:
kwincompositing           - Configure desktop effects
display                   - Display Settings
autostart                 - A configuration tool for managing which programs start up.
ebrowsing                 - Configure enhanced browsing
kcm_phonon                - Sound and Video Configuration
.... cut....
```

You could pick more than one module ie. the command:

```
kcmshell4 kwincompositing kwindecoration kwinoptions kwinrules kwinscreenedges kwintabbox
```

will start modules

[image]

```
kwincompositing           - Configure desktop effects
kwindecoration            - Configure the look and feel of window titles
kwinoptions               - Configure the window behavior
kwinrules                 - Configure settings specifically for a window
kwinscreenedges           - Configure active screen edges
kwintabbox                - Configure the behavior for navigating through windows
```

Comment: it works for kde5 with `kcmshell5`.

Comment: Very handy if you accidentally log yourself out of your "start menu" by setting "focus" level too high. "kcmshell5 kwinoptions" . Any focus level setting above medium broke "alt+f2" program running and the kde start menu (both mouse and 'windows' key shortcut.