# KDE Plasma 5 Missing Removable Devices Option

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I have upgraded my Kubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04 via Package-Manager.
Now, Plasma 5 is used.
But with Plasma 5, I am missing some functions: e.g. **Removable Devices** in System-Settings. (I used this to automatically mount some of my hard drives.)
Does anyone know where i can find this option in Plasma 5?

**EDIT:**
I tried suggestion of user26687 `kcmshell4 device_automounter_kcm`.
This brings up the settings window, but all changes made in this windows does not have any effect.
My hard drive (500GB HD) is not auto-mounted after login (like with 14.10/KDE 4)
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
I tried also the second suggestion from user26687, starting the service via: `kcmshell4 kcmkded`.
Indeed, the service was **not** running!
After starting the service via button **start**, it mounts directly my devices.
But after a system reboot, the service is not starting automatically.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted?

Comment: Is the 'Removable Device Automounter' Service running ?

Comment: Added a second edit.

Comment: This use to work. As of 9-2015 no longer solves the issue of auto-mounting of external usb drives. Haven't found a solution yet unfortunately. Changed the kded phase back to 0. Then ran the two commands. Showed auto-mounting service running. And re-click devices that I wanted auto-mounted on boot. Logging out and back in they are still mounted. But cold boot and they are lost again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer

1. Changing the `/usr/share/kde4/services/kded/device_automounter.desktop` line from

   ```
   > X-KDE-Kded-phase=1
   ```

   to:

   ```
   > X-KDE-Kded-phase=0
   ```
2. Starting 'Removable Device Automounter' from the Service Manager using

   ```
   kcmshell4 kcmkded
   ```
3. Picking the right options from the KDE 'Removable Devices module usinc

   ```
   kcmshell4 device_automounter_kcm
   ```

### Explanation

#### KDE System Settings (5)

The Kubuntu 15.04 is using KDE System Settings that can show KDE Control Modules (kcm) for the KF5/Plasma5. The removable devices kcm is from the KDE4. You could launch the KDE Control Modules from the [command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153495/how-to-launch-configure-kde-control-module-by-command-line), i.e. the following command will launch the module:

```
kcmshell4 device_automounter_kcm
```

[image: KDE Removable device windows]

#### Daemon must be running

The 'Removable Device Automounter' Service, another KDE(4) control module, needs to be running. Check with:

```
$ kcmshell4 --list | grep kcmkded
kcmkded                    - KDE Services Configuration
```

As default the ***Removable Device Automounter* is not running by default**, open the windows and start the serice:

```
kcmshell4 kcmkded
```

[image: KDE service manager windows]

#### Configure KDE Daemon start-up

1. the KDE(4) Daemon (kded) desktop files are in */usr/share/kde4/services/kded/* ;
2. the *device_automounter.desktop* has line

   > `X-KDE-Kded-phase=1`

From [HOWTO Make KDED Modules](https://github.com/vasi/kdelibs/blob/master/kded/HOWTO):

> The exact way autoloading works is
>   controlled by `X-KDE-Kded-phase=`, which may be `0`, `1` or `2` (the default).
>   Kded phase `0` means the module is always loaded by kded, even outside
>   of KDE session. It should used only by kded modules which must be
>   always running. Kded phase `1` modules are loaded right after kded
>   startup, but only during KDE startup, i.e. it is for modules that are
>   always needed by the KDE session. Phase `2` modules will be loaded
>   later.

Maybe the KF5 KDE is not detected as proper KDE?

We need to change the *device_automounter.desktop* line to:

```
> X-KDE-Kded-phase=0
```

[image: editing device_automounter.desktop]

The *Removable Device Automounter service* will be running after a **reboot**.

**Edit**

solid-device-automounter Port to KF5: https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/124730/

> Review Request #124730 - Created Aug. 13, 2015 and submitted 8 months
>   ago

Is part of the Plasma desktop 5.5 or later.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, it works a **little**....But after system-restart, the service is not running anymore.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your strong support! i will try ASAP.

Comment: i am back again, After changing **phase** from **1** to **0** it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If normally a password is required to mount your drive via gui, for example using dolphin, automount may not work, even if service is running and settings are correct. The first thing had to be tried - password check on mount disable.

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613313/kde-plasma-5-missing-removable-devices-option/613539#613539) worked for me without first step, but I have created a policy file that disables password check when mounting via udisks2.

```
root@pc:/# cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-udisks2.pkla
[Mount system devices]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system
ResultAny=auth_admin
ResultInactive=auth_admin
ResultActive=yes
```

After that little trick with policies automount started working.
I am not a linux expert, an this solution may be not a perfect one, especially in security aspect, but it worked for me at least.