# Kubuntu automatically mount USB in /media/usb0 as read-only

Tags: usb, mount, permissions, kubuntu, kde5

After a fresh install of Kubuntu 15.10, my USB drive is automatically mounted as read-only in `/media/usb0` instead of `/media/<username>/`

#### Mount output

```
$ sudo mount
…
/dev/sdb1 on /media/usb0 type vfat (rw,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,sync,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

Device is owned by `root`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4,0K janv.  1  1970 usb0/
```

#### `dmesg | tail`

I noticed `errors=remount-ro` at the end of the line of the `mount` result for the USB, so I decided to check `dmesg` for errors:

```
dmesg | tail
…
[64509.392669] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[64509.698730] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

#### `fsck`

I run

```
$ sudo fsck.vfat -a /dev/sdb1
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  3:53/6d, 4:59/6b, 5:53/64, 6:4c/6f, 7:49/73, 8:4e/66, 9:55/73, 10:58/00
…
  Not automatically fixing this.
Reclaimed 123 unused clusters (503808 bytes) in 4 chains.
Performing changes.
/dev/sdb1: 3906 files, 500874/1974252 clusters
```

#### `dmesg | tail` again

```
dmesg | tail
…
[64990.154612]  sdb: sdb1
[64990.156582] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

No more errors, but still no write permissions.

#### Question

How do I automatically mount my USB a read-write?

Comment: Your USB drive is in /dev/sdb1 if you only have 1 USB plugged in, not in /media/usb0.

Comment: `/dev/sdb1` is the device, `/media/usb0` is the mount-point.

Answer (score 3):

1. I remove `usbmount` (that I installed earlier) ;
2. configure removable devices dialog (see [KDE Plasma 5 Missing Removable Devices Option](https://askubuntu.com/a/613539/22343) ):

   ```
   kcmshell4 device_automounter_kcm
   ```
3. Starting 'Removable Device Automounter' from the Service Manager using

   ```
   kcmshell4 kcmkded
   ```
4. unplug, replug and voilà!

Comment: Wow, uninstalling usbmount did it for Kubuntu 20.04.1!